# Check if Array Position Exists

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am trying to check if the position of an array exists or not.

I am trying to output positions 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 string values from a list. Where the list is less than 5, it needs to display a '-' as the string value.

For example, a list of 3 should display: `Value, Value, Value, -, -`

I cannot however work out how to check this, and I keep getting index was out of range errors.

I have tried:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(formGuideCount[3]))
{
    game4 = formGuideCount[3];
}
else
{
    game4 = "-";
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I should be using to check if that position does not exist?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Array.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) of array to validate the index location exists.

```
if(formGuideCount.Length > 3)
{
      game4 = formGuideCount[3];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check `yourArray.Length`.

If you are using multi dimensional arrays, you can do this:

```
yourArray.GetLength(0)  //first dimension length
yourArray.GetLength(1)  //second dimension length
// and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the a `Length` member of the array

```cs
if (formGuideCount.Length > 3)
{
    game4 = formGuideCount[3];
}
else
{
    game4 = "-";
}
```